# Bott formula for projective bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a projective space one has Bott formula to compute $h^q(ℙ^n,Ω^p(k))$, where $Ω^p(k)$ is the k-twisted sheaf of sections in the p-th power of the cotangent bundle of $ℙ^n$. I am wondering if there is a similar formula to compute these dimensions when you consider a projective bundle instead of a projective space.